# change in google analytics after 3012 redirect

Tags: google-analytics, seo, http-redirect

I have my 6 months old web site and on that I had included google analytics code . And Now since I have created new domain site I'm doing 301 redirect to the new web site due to SEO purpose . In taht case do I need to change the google analytics code by resubmitting my new web site ? If I keep same old google analytics code will it affect my SEO?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and Google Analytics which belong on Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the same code. It's nothing to do with SEO.